# Altium Designer Deleted schematics completely

Tags: altium, backup, recovery

I opened up Altium after a windows update, and received this error:

```
[Error] ADF4355-3.SchDoc    Project ADF4355-3.SchDoc, could not be found and will be removed from the project.
```

I saw another post that said to just add the file back in manually after it removes it, but the file is completely gone. There is a backup that is just a blank schematic, and 2 of my libraries are gone as well. The recycle bin shows nothing.

Has anyone experienced similar problems or know if the data is recoverable?

Comment: You have a backup, right?  Restore it.

Comment: There isn't a backup. The other 4 schematics in the same project have backups. I don't know why this one didn't.

Comment: Sorry to say it but, the chances are good that you're out of luck.

Comment: Yeah I think you're probably correct. Huge bummer but it is what it is. Ok, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the original project directory (not the one listed in alitum). If the files are gone from there then check the hard drive and do a search for all schdoc files. If the file is not listed there then you have a problem.

In addition [altium can be configured to save files in a history directory](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/auto-save-and-local-history-ad?version=17.1) in the project folder. This doesn't come by default so if you didn't do that then the history files won't be of much use to you.

If the files really aren't in the project directory then they probably are gone you should see how bad you want them and pay for recovery (which may or may not work if the files have been over written, keep in mind that the more you run the drive the better chance that they have been over written).

Comment: So I did all this and there's nothing. Just a copy of a blank schematic, and the project name itself with no way to access it - it's a shortcut to a file that no longer exists, so it's gone. But thank you as well for answering. Just have to re-do it.

Comment: Sometimes backups don't work either because someone overwrites the files. It's a good idea to store your projects in one directory do a full incremental backup to that directory once a day (just in case). It takes less than 1 hour to setup a backup to potentially save weeks worth of work.